# using regex to validate date

Tags: regex

All the examples I found are checking if the string follows a certain pattern and is digit, for example `"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"`. I want to check if the date is later than a given date, for example, to check if the date follows pattern "yyyy-mm-dd" and is later than "2009-03-01". How to achieve that?

Comment: do you not have an ability to use some form of programming language? a regex really isn't the best thing for this job.

Comment: You need to convert date string to number or date object for comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this. It's like trying to use a saw to hammer in a nail.

Use whatever date parsing your language provides you and use that to perform the check.

If you need to extract the date from a string in order to do this, by all means, use a regex, but only for that part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with Sebastian's answer that regex is not the right tool for this.  That being said here is a regex that I think might work:

```
2009-(?:03-(?:0[2-9]|[1-9]\d)|(?:0[4-9]|1\d)-\d\d)|(?:20[1-9]\d|2[1-9]\d\d|[3-9]\d{3})-\d\d-\d\d
```

This is just to show you how difficult it is to read a regex solution for a problem like this, you are much better off using regex to extract the date and then compare it to your target date using language tools.